# Invoke a function/functor with parameters more than arguments

Tags: c++, function, templates, lambda, c++14

I'd like to write a template function which can invoke a function with given parameters.

For instance, I can write a simple invoke function:

```
template<class F, class... Args>
inline auto invoke(F &&func, Args&&... args) -> decltype(auto)
{
    return std::forward<F>(func)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

This `invoke` accepts same count of parameter which `f` requires. However, I want to this template function allow additional unused parameters.
That is, I want to write some code like:

```
auto f = [] (auto a) {...};
invoke(f, 1, 2, 3);
```

Here, `f` accepts only one parameter so, I wish `invoke` ignore other parameters except the first one.
This can be accomplished very easily by get arity of the lambda unless the lambda is generic.

Since `f` here is generic lambda, as far as I know, there's no general way to figure out arity of `f` without explicit instantiation of its `template operator()<...>`.

How can I wirte my `invoke`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possibility:

```
#include <utility>
#include <cstddef>
#include <tuple>

template <std::size_t... Is, typename F, typename Tuple>
auto invoke_impl(int, std::index_sequence<Is...>, F&& func, Tuple&& args)
    -> decltype(std::forward<F>(func)(std::get<Is>(std::forward<Tuple>(args))...))
{
    return std::forward<F>(func)(std::get<Is>(std::forward<Tuple>(args))...);
}

template <std::size_t... Is, typename F, typename Tuple>
decltype(auto) invoke_impl(char, std::index_sequence<Is...>, F&& func, Tuple&& args)
{
    return invoke_impl(0
                     , std::index_sequence<Is..., sizeof...(Is)>{}
                     , std::forward<F>(func)
                     , std::forward<Tuple>(args));
}

template <typename F, typename... Args>
decltype(auto) invoke(F&& func, Args&&... args)
{
    return invoke_impl(0
                     , std::index_sequence<>{}
                     , std::forward<F>(func)
                     , std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/17b0a29614e6803a)

Comment: Unrelated: For a callable object, this will sometimes call the `operator()` which has the least number of parameters. It's it possible to call the best match?

Comment: @felix I don't have an idea atm; maybe one could inherit from lambda objects and import their operators(), but at least one of them should accept all the parameters. I can't exclude other possibilities.

Comment: Oh, it's always impressive to see clever template metaprogramming code! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code I've written for my needs based on [Piotr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42268013/4131673):

```cpp
template <std::size_t... Is, typename F, typename Tuple>
void invoke_impl(
    std::index_sequence<Is...>, F&& f, Tuple&& args,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_invocable_v<F, std::tuple_element_t<Is, Tuple>...>,
                     void>* = nullptr)
{
    std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), std::get<Is>(args)...);
}

template <std::size_t... Is, typename F, typename Tuple>
void invoke_impl(
    std::index_sequence<Is...>, F&& f, Tuple&& args,
    std::enable_if_t<
        !std::is_invocable_v<F, std::tuple_element_t<Is, Tuple>...>, void>* =
        nullptr)
{
    static_assert(sizeof...(Is) > 0, "Not invocable with arguments supplied");
    if constexpr (sizeof...(Is) > 0)
    {
        invoke_impl(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Is) - 1>(),
                    std::forward<F>(f), std::move(args));
    }
}

// invokes function with possibly too many parameters provided
template <typename F, typename... Args>
void invoke(F&& f, Args&&... args)
{
    invoke_impl(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Args)>(), std::forward<F>(f),
                std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}
```

It is a little bit improved:

- it leverages `std::invoke` so it works with more use cases, like pionter to members
- it matches parameters count starting from `sizeof...(Args)` so chooses better matched `operator()` overload

Here's a demo:

```cpp
struct test
{
    void foo()
    {
        std::cout << "foo" << std::endl;
    }
    
    void operator()()
    {
        std::cout << "operator()()" << std::endl;
    }
    
    void operator()(float)
    {
        std::cout << "operator()(float)" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    test obj;
    invoke(&test::foo, &obj, 1, 2, 3); // foo
    invoke(obj); // operator()()
    invoke(obj, 1, 2, 3); // operator()(float)
    // invoke(5); // assert failed
}
```

Here's a [live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/60T3ASJCEZbwkqNp)